# How do I prevent custom full screen from resetting the scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am creating a webpage with cards that display information similar to facebook, I have added a custom "fullscreen" by changing the class to use a css that emulates full screen (see below)

```
.full-screen {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

However, I noticed that when the card is in "fullscreen" mode, the background container no longer has a scroll since there is nothing overflowing the page. So when I make the card to regular size, the scroll resets to the top. Is there anyway I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *element*.scrollTop property to get the scroll position before setting the card to fullscreen, then use that value to set the scollTop property after returning the card to its regular size.

```
var top = 0;
function getScrollPosition(){ //call this function before setting card to fullscreen
  top = document.getElementById("container").scrollTop;//make sure you give the background container an id
}
function setScrollPosition(){ //call this function after returning card to normal size
  document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = top;
}
```